# Spring-Version: 2.0.7 integrated with quartz?

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler

i'm using Spring-Version: 2.0.7, do i need to download quartz libraries and their dependencies to use it ? cause at first i though it was needed but its giving me an java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError.

So i figured that maybe it was integrated in the spring.jar since according to the 2.5 spring the bean is invoked on the application context trhough the spring library.

How ever when i removed quarta.jar, i can´t acces the JobExecutionContext class. Here is my bean declaration:

```
<bean name="exampleJob" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean">
        <property name="jobClass" value="com.bamboo.common.util.CheckAndProcessFilesJob" />
    <property name="jobDataAsMap">
    <map>
      <entry key="timeout" value="5" />
    </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The java code

```
package com.bamboo.common.util;

import org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzJobBean;


    /**
     * Created by IntelliJ IDEA.
     * User: ernestobuttolazio
     * Date: 19-may-2011
     * Time: 16:44:54
     * To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
     */
    public class CheckAndProcessFilesJob extends QuartzJobBean {
        private int timeout;

        private int contador;
         /**
       * Setter called after the ExampleJob is instantiated
       * with the value from the JobDetailBean (5)
       */
      public void setTimeout(int timeout) {
        this.timeout = timeout;
      }

     protected void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext ctx) throws JobExecutionException {
          // do the actual work
         contador += timeout;
      }

    }
```

Comment: Which version of Quartz were you trying use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Quartz 1.8.x or earlier with Spring's current wrappers.  Quartz 2.0 does not work with them.

You can use Quartz 2.0 along side Spring no problem - just not with Spring's wrappers.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use quartz 2.1.6. JobDetailFactoryBean should be used in place of JobDetailBean.The configuration will look like,

```
    <bean name="sampleJobDetail"
            class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailFactoryBean">
            <property name="jobClass"
                value="com.altisource.scheduler.jobs.SampleJob" />
            <property name="jobDataAsMap">
                <map>
                </map>
            </property>

        </bean>

        <bean id="sampleTrigger"
            class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerFactoryBean">
            <property name="jobDetail" ref="sampleJobDetail" />
            <property name="startDelay" value="30000" />
            <property name="repeatInterval" value="30000" />
            <property name="group" value="YOURCHOICE" />
        </bean>
```

If your are using quartz with clustering, the scheduler factory `org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean` will take only property `triggers` and restrict providing `jobDetails`. Make sure you configure scheduler factory `org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean` with only `triggers`.

Answer (score 0):

Quartz 2.x versions are not compatible with spring. Some classes of the earlier versions have been converted to interfaces in quartz 2.x. But still it can be used with spring, without the help of it's integration support. 
Check out this link http://shyarmal.blogspot.com/2011/07/quartz-20-schedule-cron-with-spring.html.